# Haskell's "deriving Show" in F#?

Tags: .net, haskell, f#, discriminated-union, object-to-string

In Haskell it is easy to make an algebraic type/discriminated union "displayable" as a string by simply adding `deriving Show` to the type definition.

In F# I end up writing things like:

```
type Pos = 
    | Pos of int * int
    override this.ToString() = 
        match this with
        Pos(startp, endp) -> sprintf "Pos(%d, %d)" startp endp
```

and obviously it gets much worse with more complicated types.

Any way to get something like `deriving Show` in F#?

Comment: Err, F# already does this for you automatically so you don't have to write `deriving Show`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

F# printing functions such as `printf` are able to format reasonably any data type if you use the `%A` format specifier (they use `ToString` if you specify `%O`). You can implement `ToString` using `sprintf` which returns the formatted string:

```
type Pos =  
    | Pos of int * int 
    override x.ToString() = sprintf "%A" x
```

This prints for example "Pos (1, 2)" and it works for most of the F# types (lists, unions, records, tuples). It's a bit longer than just adding `deriving Show` but at least you don't have to implement the printing yourself.

Comment: and how could one achieve `deriving Read` in F#?